# Is there any end date for Microsoft full .NET Framework 4.8

Tags: .net, frameworks

I am hearing that Microsoft is not going to provide any further updates for the full .NET Framework after version 4.8. So my question is what will be the last Microsoft supported full .NET Framework version after .NET 4.6?

I am trying to get proper answer instead of just suggestion to move everything in .NET Core.

Comment: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-framework

Comment: you can see here all the .Net framework End of life: https://learn.microsoft.com/he-il/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-framework

Comment: and you can see all current vulnerabilities here: https://www.cvedetails.com/version-list/26/2002/1/Microsoft-.net-Framework.html

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[As documented](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-framework), The .Net framework is a component of the Windows operating system:

> Beginning with version 4.5.2 and later, .NET Framework is defined as a component of the Windows operating system (OS).

[Therefor, it's lifecycle is tied to the lifecycle of the OS it's a part of.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-framework-48)

> .NET Framework is a component of the Windows OS. Components receive the same support as their parent product or platform.

[.Net Framework 4.8 is a part of Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies#net-framework-48), and therefor it's life cycle is dictated by the Windows 10 life cycle (unless, of course, it's going to be a part of the next Windows OS, and that will extend it's life cycle even more).

Comment: Microsoft just announced eol on Windows 10 is 2025. Does this apply to. Net framework 4.8 too?

Comment: I don't know. But as far as I understand, not if it will be a part of the next OS

Comment: It is included in Windows 11 according this [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/on-windows-11) page. Life time extended to at least Windows 11 now.

Answer (score 4):

Currently there is no end of support date for the full .NET Framework 4.8:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-framework